# Observeable stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to make an ObserveableCollection of ListBoxes that will be my columns, and ObserveableCollection of Buttons that will be my tasks of the ListBox.

The problem is i created an Horizontal StackPanel.

```
<StackPanel Name="panel" Orientation="Horizontal">
</StackPanel>
```

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ListBox currentList;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            currentList = new ListBox();
            Button b1 = new Button();
            b1.Content = "Add Card";
            b1.Height = 23;
            b1.Width = 100;
            b1.Click += B1_Click;
            currentList.Items.Add(b1);
            panel.Children.Add(currentList);
        }

        private void B1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button currentButton = (Button)sender;
            currentList = ((ListBox)currentButton.Parent);
            Button bt = new Button();
            bt.Content = "task";
            bt.Height = 23;
            bt.Width = 100;
            currentList.Items.Add(bt);
        }
    }
```

So this is the result I'm getting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/My44S.jpg

That's exactly what i needs except i need to bind the StackPanel problem is it is impossible to bind it and i was not able to achieve the same result with a Horizontal ListBox, for some reason when i add the Vertical ListBoxes and then add buttons inside them the result is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRkSy.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can better off achieve what you're trying to do but using the `ItemsControl` in `Xaml`. This works by binding to the `ObservableCollection` and creating a `ListBox` foreach item in the collection. the `ListBox` is then bound to the `ObservableCollection` inside to display each individual item.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="100" Height="auto">

            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> _myCollection;

public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> MyCollection
{
    get { return _myCollection; }
    set { _myCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged }
}
```

Comment: Thank yo very much it helped me!

Comment: @ArikShapiro Great! If it solved your problem consider clicking the tick to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Is it possible to assign an ObservableCollection to a ListBox and also make the ListBox the logical Parent of the Objects inside the Collection? What i'm trying to do is when i click the Button in certain List i need to be able to get the ListBox inside the Button_Click, I'm trying to get the parent of the sender.

Comment: Hi, you could use a helper method or class to search the visual tree for the first parent of type ListBox. https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/